# What is the relation between 32bit CRC and the data word size?

Tags: crc32

if we take 32-bit CRC then the data word size will be 2 to the power of 32(2**32) plus 32 bit for CRC.... or not? Am I missing something?

If I want to write a code in Microsoft Visual C++ for implementing 32-bit CRC then what is the data type I can use? Maybe I am missing the point and talking rubbish.

Basically it is my assignment to implement 32-bit CRC and I am completely at a loss how to go about it.

Sorry if the question is vague. Any help toward implementation, logic, or basic fundamentals will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

CRC-32 is basically the act of dividing two polynomials and returning the remainder.

Recommended introductory reading:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check
- http://www.mathpages.com/home/kmath458.htm
- http://www.ross.net/crc/download/crc_v3.txt